# Tooltipster jQuery plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using [Tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#demos) jQuery plugin in my WordPress theme but when I want to use it with HTML content it shows no result what's my problem?

I wrote these in my main-function.js file

```
jQuery(function($){
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster(
content: $('<span><strong>This text is in bold case !</strong></span>')
    );
});
});
```

HTML

```
<span class="tooltip">Sightly Newer</span>
```

This plugin works well but doesn't work with HTML content.

Comment: Purpose of your question's title??? BTW, why nesting document ready handlers?

Comment: put content in PlainObject
`$('.tooltip').tooltipster({
content: $('<span><strong>This text is in bold case !</strong></span>')
    });`

Comment: sorry wrong question title , how can i edit it?